# How can I connect a SQLite local database to a HTML frontend?

Tags: javascript, python, html, sqlite, database-connection

I've recently ported a simple database from Ms Access to SQLite, because I wanted an open source option. Now I'm facing the problem of developing a visual form for data entry in that database.

This related question ([HTML/JS as interface to local SQLite database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10470240/html-js-as-interface-to-local-sqlite-database)) pretty much summaries what I want to do: create an HTML/JavaScript frontend for data entry in a SQLite local database. In that thread, the user solved the issue by creating a local web server via Python script.

**The question is: how do I connect my HTML file to that local web server?** Is that via PHP or something similar? Please point me to the right research direction. Thank you!

Comment: Usually you would place the files on the server.

Comment: `<form action="http://yourserver.com/your_server_side_script.py">`

Comment: Thanks IanAuld and Marc B, but I wanted more general answers (i. e., I don't understand anything yet about local servers interacting with SQLite).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should use PHP or something similar, possibly Ruby on Rails or Django.  The last two make life really easy and help abstract the database.

Comment: Thanks! If I chose Ruby on Rails, could I still use the same local web server created by Python?

Comment: No, Ruby on Rails is it's own web server.  You can see more information here:   https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9gKyW9Uq6wo  If you want to stick with python, then you should use Django